Issue accessing static files in Next.js with dynamic routes in App Router
I'm working on a Next.js application and encountering an issue when trying to access static files while using dynamic routes in the App Router.
My project structure is as follows:
/public
  /images
    img.png
/app
  /[companyslug]
    page.jsx

When I try to access the static file at localhost:3000/images/img.png, I get an error indicating that the companyslug is not found, as if Next.js is trying to interpret the /images/img.png path as a dynamic route.
Is there a way to configure Next.js to properly serve the static files from the public directory without conflicting with the dynamic routes?

................................

....................
